# connect java app to mongoDB on openshift cloud

Tags: java, mongodb, openshift

i'm trying to connect local java app to openshift MongoDB using this code

```
String mongoUri = "mongodb://admin:password@myServerIP:27017/";                        
MongoClient mongoClient;

mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoUri));

DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mongo");
System.out.println("Successfully connected to MongoDB ");
```

but it connect to local machine MongDB ? it give me this error ?

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=remoteIpAddress:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

i'm search and i found solution (port forward) but i can't do it , any one give me solution , thanks .

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: We would be able to help if you can pass the error. Are you behind any proxies? I meant corporate firewalls.

Comment: it's not connect to remote mongo database